# Error using a Bean in a JSP page

Tags: java, jsp

I have a bean with a method I need to use to populate a table in a JSP page, my JSP is

```
<%@page import="domain.docs"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="beans.statsbeans" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:useBean id="stats" scope="session" class="beans.statsbeans" />
<jsp:setProperty name="report" property="*" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <%
        String opcion = request.getParameter("value");    
        %>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Reporte Excel</title>
    </head>
    <body>


        <%  
        List<docs> doclist = report.getExcel(value);

        for (int i=0; i<lista.size();i++){

            out.println("Record No"+i);
        }

        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Basically the page now is just a dummy one while I test why it doesnt work, the bean has a method called `getExcel(String value)` that return a List of objetcs.

The Stacktrace says that there is a NULL pointer exception when the method in the bean is called.

When I debug it, the JSP page seems to pass the value correctly but the bean is not receiving it

If i point my mouse over the JSP repor.getExcel() it says No current context (Stack Frame)

Any idea?

edit: ADDING COMPLETE STACKTRACE:

```
Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:575)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:88)
causa raíz

java.lang.NullPointerException
    beans.EstadisticaBean.obtenerExcel(EstadisticaBean.java:43)
    org.apache.jsp.formulario.reporte_005fexcel_jsp._jspService(reporte_005fexcel_jsp.java:123)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:88)
```

The thing is I never use JSP, I need to add this functionality to an old development, normally I would use JSF for everything

Comment: Post the code. Post the complete exception stack trace. Side note: you should really read a more recent JSP tutorial: you're using them as if we were still in 1999, with no tags, no JSP EL, no JSTL, no MVC.

Comment: beans.statsbeans sound very much like a **package  name** not like a class?!

Comment: Your JSP code doesn't match with the exception. BTW, the JSP code wouldn't even compile. Post the real code. And look at what could be null at line 43 of EstadisticaBean.java.

Answer (score 0):

You must set attributes property="listDoc" and value="<%=list%>" 
Where listDoc is your member beans.statsbeans class